# Whats my mistake (bubblesort) ? the first 3 numbers are the same and the last 4 numbers aswell?

Tags: java

The first 3 numbers that I get are always 0, and the last 4 numbers are mostly the same. I have no idea where my mistake is...

```
public static boolean sortieren(int[] value) {

    boolean check = false;
    int oldvalue = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < value.length - 1; i++) {
        if (value[i] > value[i + 1]) { // vergleicht welche Stelle größer
                                        // ist
            oldvalue = value[i];
            value[i] = value[i + 1];
            value[i + 1] = oldvalue;
            check = true;
        }
    }
    return check;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int laenge = 8; // Array definiert
    int[] arr = new int[8];
    Random randomgenerator = new Random(); // Random definiert
    for (int i = 0; i < laenge; i++) {
        arr[i] = randomgenerator.nextInt(100);

        while (sortieren(arr) == true) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is pass-by-value.  Create your array first, display it then sort it and print each step.  This will help you build and understand what is going on.  No need for the boolean function.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb I don't think that's an issue here.

Comment: Yeah, pass-by-value vs. pass-by-reference isn't relevant here. However, the fact that the code is sorting the entire array each time a new element is set is.

Comment: Or use existing methods like `Arrays.sort(arr);`

Comment: @JimmyJames, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want your while loop inside the for loop that builds the array.  You are sorting the array before it is full which is moving all the zeros (in the uninitialized array) to the beginning and then continuing on.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I would use to solve your problem. You have to pass the back to the main function so you can print it out from there.

```
public class BubbleSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int laenge = 8; // Array definiert
    int[] arr = new int[8];
    Random randomgenerator = new Random(); // Random definiert
    for (int i = 0; i < laenge; i++) {
        arr[i] = randomgenerator.nextInt(100);
    }
    arr = bubbleSort(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < laenge; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}


static int[] bubbleSort(int[] array) {
        int swaps;
        boolean done = false;
        int temp;
        while(!done) {
            swaps = 0;
            for(int i=0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
                if(array[i] > array[i+1]) {
                    temp = array[i+1];
                    array[i+1] = array[i];
                    array[i] = temp;
                    swaps++;
                }
            }
            if (swaps == 0) {
                done = true;
            }
        }
        return array;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Looks like @JimmyJames is right. You don't have to pass the array back. I did not know that worked it Java.

Comment: If you want to do it your way you need to check that you are not swapping 0s or you swap your randomly generated value to the end because of all the initialised zeros.